# JS - Defining display sencha window function

Tags: function, extjs

Im trying to assign this process to a function so I can add a listener to a button but it keeps giving me an "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list".  Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

```js
function popWindow() {
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    bodyStyle: "background-color:#FFFFFF",
    title: 'QA Tools',
    height: 300,
    width:400,
    layout: 'absolute',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        x: 15,
        y: 35,
        height: 35,
        width: 125,
        text: 'Sell Listings',
        itemId: 'sellBtn',
    }, {
  xtype: 'button',
        x: 15,
        y: 90,
        height: 35,
        width: 125,
        text: 'Set SP Cycle to 1 Min',
        itemId: 'sp1MinBtn',
 }, {
  xtype: 'button',
        x: 15,
        y: 145,
        height: 35,
        width: 175,
        text: 'Set Single AP Cycle to 1 min',
        itemId: 'singleAPMinBtn',
 }, {
  xtype: 'button',
        x: 15,
        y: 200,
        height: 35,
        width: 175,
        text: 'Set Grouped AP Cycle to 1 min',
        itemId: 'groupedAPMinBtn',
 },  {
  xtype: 'textfield',
        x: 170,
        y: 36,
        height: 30,
        width: 175,
        allowBlank: false,
        minLength: 7,
        maxLength: 7,
        emptyText: 'Enter Listing ID',
        itemId: 'sellListingField',
 }]
}
}).show();
```

Can anyone help me get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your JavaScript is not valid.  Usually a warning like that means you have some malformed code.  I recommend running it through a prettifier [like this one](https://beautifier.io/) to help line the braces up and find the problem.  When we do that with your code, we see 2 mistakes.

1. You don't close out of the function with an ending brace
2. You have 1 too many braces before the .show

It should look like this

```
function popWindow() {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        bodyStyle: "background-color:#FFFFFF",
        title: 'QA Tools',
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        layout: 'absolute',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            x: 15,
            y: 35,
            height: 35,
            width: 125,
            text: 'Sell Listings',
            itemId: 'sellBtn',
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            x: 15,
            y: 90,
            height: 35,
            width: 125,
            text: 'Set SP Cycle to 1 Min',
            itemId: 'sp1MinBtn',
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            x: 15,
            y: 145,
            height: 35,
            width: 175,
            text: 'Set Single AP Cycle to 1 min',
            itemId: 'singleAPMinBtn',
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            x: 15,
            y: 200,
            height: 35,
            width: 175,
            text: 'Set Grouped AP Cycle to 1 min',
            itemId: 'groupedAPMinBtn',
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            x: 170,
            y: 36,
            height: 30,
            width: 175,
            allowBlank: false,
            minLength: 7,
            maxLength: 7,
            emptyText: 'Enter Listing ID',
            itemId: 'sellListingField',
        }]
    }).show();
}
```